# How I get the right exception for wrong Datatype input?

Tags: c#, exception, while-loop, int, tryparse

Sorry, first of all, I´m new in C#
I´m trying to get the right way to handle the wrong input!
In my small calculator I have ints for the input and to calculate with, but I how do I handle it when I have an input like: "hi", what is not an int?
AND I want to loop if you make a wrong input again and I don´t know how to loop it....

Isn´t there anything like:  `if (x != int32)` ?
I have tried it this way:

```
               Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number: ");
               while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x))
               {
                   Console.WriteLine("Invalid input! Try again");
                   if (Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x))
                   {
                       break;
                   }
                }
```

Comment: remove the if and break. its redundant, also if you step through this you would understand how its working

Comment: @TheGeneral thanks a lot!! However is there anything like ```if (x != int32)```

Comment: @Dominik43566 `!Int32.TryParse` this is exactly what this does

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the following

```
int x;

Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number: ");
while (!Int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x))
   Console.WriteLine("Invalid input! Try again");

Console.WriteLine($"You had one job and it was a success : {x}");
```

Here is the deal

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string, `Int32.TryParse(` *returns* `true` or `false` if it can parse a `string` to an `int`.

The loop will continually loop while `Console.ReadLine()` cannot be parsed to an `int`

As soon as it can, the loop condition is not met and execution continues to the last `Console.WriteLine`